# Phusion passenger crash and restart rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, passenger

My website runs normally to me but CTR is very low so I open the error log and see something like from this file:

[crash log](https://gist.github.com/tranvictor/1c8275ed18b92e5eb332)

What is this and how can I fix this?
P/s: I'm using Phusion Passenger 4.0.10, nginx 1.0.15, rails 3.2.12, ruby 1.9.3p448, Centos

Comment: Seem like a bug in passenger https://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=889 upgrade to newer version may fix it.

Comment: I already read the link before I posted this question and tried to upgrade libev but nothing has changed.

Comment: Passenger developer here. Are you able to reproduce this problem consistently? Has the log output changed between 4.0.10 and the latest version?

Comment: I'm not sure about reproducing the problem, it happened quite frequently when I was bringing traffics to the sites. I also commented on your gist which is likely the same as mine, @Hongli

Comment: If you encounter the crash again, could you update your crash log? The latest version contains more debugging details which will aid me in analyzing the problem.

Comment: ok, thank you for willing to help me.